# Separate root for subdirectory uses wrong location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have been trying to setup a directory to use a seperate root directory (or alias).

```
location ~ \.php$ # root location
{
        try_files $uri @php;
        include /etc/openresty/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ^~ /sub2/
{
    rewrite_log on;
    alias /var/www/sub2/;
    location ~ \.php$
{
    try_files $uri @ono_php;
    include /etc/openresty/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    try_files $uri @ono_main_cache;
}

location @ono_php
{
    rewrite ^/sub2/(.+)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
}

location @ono_main_cache
{
    if ( $http_accept_encoding !~ gzip )
    {
        rewrite ^/sub2/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    }
    if ( $query_string )
    {
            rewrite ^/sub2/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    }
    try_files /var/www/sub2/data/cache/html$uri.html.gz @ono_php;
    add_header      Content-Encoding gzip;
    gzip off;
    default_type text/html;
}
```

There is more in the overall nginx configuration for the domain, but I've only included what is relevant.

To overview, I want the `/sub2/` to use the root/alias `/var/www/sub2/`, rather than the default `/var/www/site/`. That works correctly. However, all URLs that don't load a file should be redirected to `index.php` as in the `@ono_php` block. However, they use the first location block listed (with # root location appended to it). So if I load the URL:

https://example.com/sub2/contact

It loads the same URL as:

https://example.com/contact

How can I get the block @ono_php to use the `location ~ \.php$` defined inside `location ^~ /sub2/`?

Comment: You have specified the URL as `/index.php?request=$1` which is handled by the first `location` block. Maybe you mean to use `/sub2/index.php?request=$1`?

Comment: @RichardSmith - It produces the same result

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of issues. The main being I set the root/alias to `/var/www/sub2` and when requests were made, they had that directory appended from the URL, e.g. the path requested was `/var/www/sub2/sub2/url` - where `sub2/url` is the URL. Changing the root to `/var/www` fixed this.

```
location ^~ /sub2
{
    root /var/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @ono_main_cache;

    location ~ \.php$
    {
            include /etc/openresty/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

location @ono_php
{
    rewrite ^/sub2/(.*)$ /sub2/index.php?request=$1 last;
}

location @ono_main_cache
{
    if ( $http_accept_encoding !~ gzip )
    {
        rewrite ^/sub2/(.*)$ /sub2/index.php?request=$1 last;
    }
    if ( $query_string )
    {
            rewrite ^/sub2/(.*)$ /sub2/index.php?request=$1 last;
    }
    try_files /sub2/data/cache/html$uri.html.gz @ono_php;
    add_header      Content-Encoding gzip;
    gzip off;
    default_type text/html;
}
```